# Call asynctask in handler repeateadly and updating UI hangs app

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I'm trying to call asynctask in handler repeateadly and updating adapter, but it hangs UI. Now m confused so Please tell me how to call asynctask repeatedly and upade UI.I have make sure that asynctask will call only once till it does not get finish with the help of flagAsync.
Handler code is below.

```
  private void RefreshData() {

         mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            // Create runnable for posting
            mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    InsideHandler();

                }

            };

            int delay = 500;

            int period = 500;

            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {

                    mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

                }

            }, delay, period);

        }
```

Asynctask is called inside Handler - code is below -

```
   private void InsideHandler() {

    if(aController.isNetworkAvailable() && flagAsync == 0)
            {

                flagAsync =1;

         adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
                    MsgList.clear();
                    MsgList.addAll(db.getMsgList(teacherId));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


           PostMsgData(strUrl, strJson);

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                            postDataAsyn.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                        else
                            postDataAsyn.execute();

    }
        }

 private void PostMsgData(final String strUrl, final String strJson) {



        postDataAsyn = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);


                try {
                    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(strUrl).openConnection()));
                    httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpcon.connect();

                    byte[] outputBytes = strJson.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(outputBytes);

                    os.close();

                    int responseCode = httpcon.getResponseCode();

                    if(responseCode == 200)
                    {
                        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpcon.getInputStream());
                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                inputStream);

                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                inputStreamReader);

                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                        while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                        }

                        return stringBuilder.toString();

                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {


                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "ERROR";

            }



            @Override
            protected void onCancelled()
            {
                super.onCancelled();

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            }
            }
```

Comment: have you tried runOnUiThread()

Comment: Check my ques i have added PostMsgData  method

Comment: @Haroon - no i didnt tried runOnUiThread(). Yes i m confused so m asking here about solution.

Comment: I think Async task shoukd be called from UI thread not from handler

Comment: then how to call it repeatedly. that will be great if you can give me code

Comment: Hi Sarika,What is the use of PostMsgData method?

Comment: just AsyncTask implementation is inside PostMsgData method

Answer (score 0):

```
  mHandler = new Handler() {
   @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    InsideHandler();
    }
});
  }
};
```

Can you try this

Comment: Thanks for your help.I used above code + Timer to repeate the task.But it still hangs UI.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you to solve your problem. Suggest you to use runonthreadui for handle load.

http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.app.Activity/runOnUiThread

And Don't call asyntask from handler.

Answer (score 0):

use the code Haroon provided and let the timer out. use a runnable as timer this will fix your issue(i hope haha:) )

Comment: i did but still ui hangs. :-(